# Удалить html теги из текстового файла Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте! У меня есть текстовый файл, в котором есть что-то похожее на html теги(<какой-то_текст>) и просто текст. Нужно написать на Java метод для удаления всех html тегов из этого файла (по сути задание найти в файле символы < и > и удалить их и текст между ними) с помощью регулярных выражений. Вот то, что я пытался сам написать, но программа почему-то удаляет весь текст из файла, а не только html теги.

```
public static void DeleteTags(File f) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f));
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String tmp;
    Pattern patternHTML = Pattern.compile("^<([!a-zA-Z]+)>$");
    while ((tmp = input.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] words = tmp.split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            Matcher matcherHTML = patternHTML.matcher(words[i]);
            if (!matcherHTML.matches()) {
                list.add(words[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            output.write(list.get(i) + " ");
        }
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Парсить html регулярками - [очень плохая идея](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3212712). Возьмите специальную библиотеку для парсинга, например JSOUP.

Comment: У меня просто задание именно через регулярки это сделать. По сути задание найти в файле символы < и > и удалить их и текст между ними

Answer (score 1):

Здесь предполагается, что текстовый файл находится в ресурсах.
  Если нужно учитывать пробелы, то просто уберите `.map(String::trim)`из стрима.

```
 public static List<String> readFileWord(String path) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    return Files.lines(Paths.get(Main.class.getResource(path).toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .map(s -> s.split("<?\\S\\w+>"))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
            .map(String::trim)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    List<String> list = readFileWord("/text.txt");
    System.out.println(list.toString());
}
```

**text.txt содержит:**

```
<div> norma </div>
<head>bla bla bla</head>
<title> hi people! </title>
<d> dfsdf </l>
просто текст
```

**Результат работы функции:**

```
 norma, bla bla bla, hi people!, dfsdf, просто текст
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {
   string a = /* прочитай файл и заполни  */ ;
   string b = /* то что заменить */;
   string c = /* на что заменить */;
   a.replaceAll(a,c);
 }
```