# Замена разделителя в строке

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка с реквизитами вида AAA,BBBB,AAAAA
И есть строка с реквизитами вида AAA, BBBB, AAAAA
Так же бывают AAA,BBBB, AAAAA или AAA  ,BBBB, AAAAA

Хочу всё привести к AAA, BBBB, AAAAA, но не разобраться какую регулярку написать. Конечно есть вариант разбить всё по , а потом делать трим всему а после пойти и собрать через нужный мне разделитель, но может кто знает как это одной регуляркой сделать?

Comment: См. напр. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/811857/229437. У тебя реквизиты слитные, так что разделитель будет тупо `[ ,]`.

Comment: @Akina ну я так понял там и описан этот же путь, разбиваю строку по , делаю трим всему и собираю обратно через нужный разделитель, я это и так понимаю. Меня скорее интересует заменить просто в одно движение все запятые с прилегающими к ним пробелами в строке на [ ,]

Comment: Как я понимаю, там при указанном разделителе будет строка порезана по запятой ИЛИ пробелу, затем удалены пустые элементы (скажем, если где-то разделитель был пробел И запятая, в этом месте будет два деления, и "средний" элемент будет пустой строкой - именно такой элемент будет удалён), и затем строка будет обратно собрана с нужным разделителем. Ну если хочешь - задай жадный поиск `[ ,]+` и замену на `, `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Перечисление всех возможных комбинаций запятой и пробела, разделяя |
String regexp = ", |,| ,";

// Более общий вариант поиска с учетом множества пробелов
// String regexp = " *, *";

String sep = ", ";

System.out.println("AAA,BBBB,AAAAA".replaceAll(regexp, sep));
System.out.println("AAA, BBBB, AAAAA".replaceAll(regexp, sep));
System.out.println("AAA,BBBB, AAAAA".replaceAll(regexp, sep));
System.out.println("AAA ,BBBB, AAAAA".replaceAll(regexp, sep));
// AAA, BBBB, AAAAA
```